# Can't remove underline link from image

Tags: html

I have animated GIF that, upon hovering over it, creates an underline link (turquoise-colored). I've tried adding the style "text-decoration: none;" in the a tag, but nothing happens. Please help. Here's my HTML code:

```
<aside id="ad1">
     <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.cnn.com/" target="_blank">
     <img border="0"; src="images/cnnnews.gif" alt="cnnnewsgif"></a>
</aside>
```

EDIT (06/17/14):

Here's a snapshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: can you recreate this  a fiddle?

Comment: is there any sort of a:hover code in your stylesheet?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on my end.... http://jsfiddle.net/D797f/

Comment: your image tag is not closed by the way; it could be causing some unintended issues.

Comment: @agconti This is using HTML 5 tags and in HTML 5, `img` doesn't require closing.

Comment: This is unrelated, but you do have a `;` after the border attribute.

Comment: @JeremyMiller fair point.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<a style="text-decoration: none;"`

Add a class e.g.

```
<aside id="ad1">
     <a class="imglink" href="http://www.cnn.com/" target="_blank">
     <img border="0" src="images/cnnnews.gif" alt="cnnnewsgif" /></a>
</aside>
```

And add the following css to in the header

```
<style type="text/css">
        .imglink, .imglink:hover{
            text-decoration: none;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce it, but your issue is probably either some sort of syntax error or that you're setting `text-decoration: none` for the link, but not the hovered link. Just use the `:hover` selector and define your style in the `head`.

```
<head>
    <!--other head stuff-->
    <style>
      img, img:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <aside id="ad1">
        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.cnn.com/" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" src="images/cnnnews.gif" alt="cnnnewsgif"/></a>
    </aside>
</body>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/LGZEU/)

(Though it won't show you much)

Comment: It's not working. Please read my comments above. Here's a snapshot of what I'm getting:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/33f3jw1.jpg

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and then tried Firefox (Since I'm assuming they're both used widely around the country). Both browsers have the same issues.

Comment: @user3385997 No one has been able to reproduce your issue: can you try demonstrating it in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?